# YouTube Embedded player view controller not deallocating

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, ytplayerview

I'm using a `YTPlayer` view controller to play youtube videos in my app. When an instance is created, memory usage spikes up to 80 MB on the simulator. I expect it to go back to its normal value (35 MB) when the view is exited but it doesn't. All the other view controllers release memory when I exit them except this one.

I tried dismissing the view controller in `viewWillDisappear` method but no success.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have close option on the view controller on which you are embedding this view controller?

Comment: @iYoung not exactly. I'm using SWRevealView to make a swipe menu containing the list of all the view controllers. So by exiting a view controller, I mean swiping right and selecting another one.